# Find controls that have a property equal to a value

Tags: c#, wpf

how to implement a method that given a property name and a property value, finds all the controls that match.
Is it posible to modify this code for doing that: [WPF. Find control that binds to specific property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959421/wpf-find-control-that-binds-to-specific-property)

For example, retrieving all the controls that have the the property "ControlExtender.Isprintable" to "True".
`<component views:ControlExtender.Isprintable ="true">`

Comment: Can you share with us what you've tried so far and point out why that doesn't work? Also, a specific use case would be useful.

Comment: Since ControlExtender.IsPrintable seems to be an attached property you could maintain a list of elements to which the IsPrintable was attached to. Inside the property changed callback you could do that.

IsPrintable by default should be false however everytime you attached it to an element and set true to it the property changed event will fire. Inside the handler you could just add the associated element to your backing list. That easy :)