# WPF: How can I show error "bubbles" on each control with validation errors when mouse enters the Save button?

Tags: wpf, validation

**UPDATE:**

Let me be more specific about what I'm after... I have error borders around my controls using the error template.  Those show up all the time since they use the INotifyData interface.  But additionally, I want to display bubbles next to controls in an error state when the user mouses over the Save button.

I have pretty much every component of this solution working: I have popups that I can make appear on my controls through the code behind.  I have validating viewmodels using the validation framework to give me the borders.  And my Save buttons disable themselves as necessary through "CanSave".  I also know how to wire up an event handler to listen for mouse enter on the save button.

But now I need to somehow find all the controls in error so I can trigger their bubbles... I can find all the properties in error via the dictionary of properties to error messages in my INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation.... But how to find the DependencyObjects in the visual tree for each property?

I found this [WPF. Find control that binds to specific property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959421/wpf-find-control-that-binds-to-specific-property), but it seems pretty heavy handed.

The .NET validation framework somehow does this, right? Validator.TryValidateObject must search through all the properties with ValidationAttributes, then finds their Dependency objects so it can activate the ErrorTemplate on them... If could access the dependency objects, I could activate their error templates as necessary.  How does it do it?  Through the bindings?  Or is there a better way?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: That totally depends on how you have implemented your validation. I use the `IDataErrorInfo` interface to highlight validation errors, but mine are always visible, so I'm not sure what you've done.

Comment: Sorry - my description was vague.  I added some clarification just now.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to display the bubbles when you mouse over the save button? Would it be acceptable to display the bubbles whenever the control is invalid?

Comment: The customer's requirements.  They find it visually distracting to have bubbles all over the place while filling in the form... They want to just get a hint via the error borders, but then get the specific problems pointed out when they go to save.  It's about not cluttering up the interface.

Comment: That is understandable. Are these controls standard microsoft controls or are they custom ones you have created? I am currently thinking along the lines of creating an attached behaviour or having the custom control expose a way of doing this.

Comment: They are all standard, though some are user controls which combine several standard controls.  I think I am giving up though... It just requires too much glue.  I'm trying out a method by which I wait several seconds before displaying the bubbles... I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to only show the error border once the Save button has been clicked as well as the bubble?

Comment: Hmm, I'll check on that and let you know.  That said, I know how to do that one :-)

Comment: That was why I was asking :). If it can be done that way then you can achieve it with what you already have in place and a few modifications