# How to find the control that binds to a specific property in Silverlight

Tags: data-binding, .net-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I would like to get the control that binds to a specific (Observable) property.

I found an SO answer similar to exactly what I want but the solution is for WPF:

[WPF. Find control that binds to specific property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959421/wpf-find-control-that-binds-to-specific-property)

Unfortunately, I cannot reference the WindowsBase.dll assembly that defines the **MarkupObject** and the **MarkupWriter**.

It results in the following error:

> You can't add a reference to WindowsBase.dll as it was not built
>   against the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight projects will only work
>   with Silvelight assemblies.

Is there an equivalent way I can do the same for Silverlight?