# Get XAML controls by their bound properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to get the controls in XAML using the properties bound to them,

something like this:

```
 Account acc = GetFromDB(id);
 foreach (var prop in acc.GetType().GetProperties())
 {
      Control control = GetControl(prop.Name);
      //Then I want to set properties like Foreground for the control
 }

 private Control GetControl(string propertyName)
 {
      //getting the control bound to the propertyName
 }
```

and say that this is XAML code:

```
            <Label>Name</Label>
            <TextBox Name="txtName" 
                     Grid.Column="1" 
                     Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1">Debt</Label>
            <TextBox Name="txtDebt" 
                     Grid.Column="1" 
                     Grid.Row="1" 
                     Text="{Binding Debt}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2">Join Date</Label>
            <DatePicker Name="dpJoin" 
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        Grid.Row="2" 
                        Text="{Binding JDate}"/>
```

Comment: set the Name Property on a Control, like `<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" />`, now you can access this control in code behind with this name, like `myTextBox.Width = 300;`

Comment: I set it in the code above, now skip that solution!

Comment: This is what exactly I was looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35695596/6197785

Answer (score 0):

Just set `x:Name` and find control you need by [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx).
If you need a specific control name, you can bind it like `x:Name="{Binding Name}"`

```
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) 
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null) return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is a sample ho do it by property name:

```
public static T FindVisualChildByName<T>(FrameworkElement depObj, string name) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i) as FrameworkElement;
                if (child != null && child is T && child.Name == name)
                    return (T)child;

                T childItem = FindVisualChildByName<T>(child, name);
                if (childItem != null)
                    return childItem;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

There is example how to use this methods.

`FindVisualChildByName<T>` method have two parameters, first is the page or control instance where you will seeking for, and second is control name to find on the page.

Not sure how to get `Frame` or page instance in WPF, but in UWP it looks like this:

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
var textBox = VisualHelper.GetChildOfType<TextBox>(frame);
var anotherTextBox = VisualHelper.FindVisualChildByName<TextBox>(frame, "MyTextBox");
```

Or cast like this:

```
var obj = VisualHelper.FindVisualChildByName<object>(frame, "MyTextBox");
var type = obj.GetType();
var textBox = System.Convert.ChangeType(obj, type);
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code, what I was expecting is a method that takes just a string value (that is the name of the property) and returns the Control bound to that property

Comment: See question's EDIT

Comment: But the control might be a `TextBox`, `CheckBox` , `DatePicker`.. etc. I just don't know neither the property nor its bound control!

Comment: Here is a full [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/fbee9021ef17407bc3aaa79ff282f25178a0c4af/Styles%20%26%20Templates/FindingElementsInTemplates)

Comment: You can try to cast control by `System.Convert.ChangeType(obj, type);` See EDIT again